# Search through nested array, return only url value from one column

Tags: php, arrays, csv, foreach, while-loop

I have an array that looks like so, which is generated by:

```
$file = fopen($savedSource,"r");

            while(! feof($file)) {
                $data = (fgetcsv($file));
            }

Array
(
    [0] => First Name
    [1] => Last Name
    [2] => Title
    [3] => Company / Account
    [4] => Email
    [5] => Lead ID
    [6] => Profile Image
Zelayas
    [7] => Zelayas
    [8] => 
    [9] => Kramer
    [10] => zel@somewhere.com
    [11] => 123456
    [12] => https://media.com/0f48c22.jpg
Kanngiesser
    [13] => Kanngiesser
    [14] => 
    [15] => Johnson
    [16] => kanngie@somewhere.com
    [17] => 7891234
    [18] => https://media.com/135f3b7.jpg
```

I would like to be able to store those URL's into just one simple (no nesting) array, so that the result becomes:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => https://media.com/0f48c22.jpg
        [1] => https://media.com/135f3b7.jpg
```

=== EDIT ===
From selected answer, I've been able to achieve what I am after basically.

```
        $new_array = array();
        foreach($data as $a){
            if(substr( $a, 0, 4 ) === "http"){
                array_push($new_array, $a);
            }
        }
```

As a result, $new_array is now giving me

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://media.com/0f48c22.jpg
Kanngiesser
    [1] => https://media.com/135f3b7.jpg
Mostovoy
```

So it seems that the script is seeing the last field of the current line AND the first field of the next line AS ONE FIELD.

Comment: my lazy way: loop and check if values starts with "http"

Comment: `$urls = preg_grep('/^http/', $array);`

Comment: Not sure if the title of this question is accurate. "Every nth" suggests something like "get every 6th," but your example makes it sound like you want elements with a certain value. Can you plz clarify?

Comment: @mopo922 correct. OP's question suggests items 6 and 24 should contain URL as well. This could be accomplished with division with remainder(%) then

Comment: if your really after the url's its better to check for that, in case the input changes one day

Comment: True, but still. Question is unclear on that part

Comment: considering how fast we respond to questions, OP's should not be allowed to leave after posting

Comment: @mopo922 Tried improving the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substr` to detect `http` on the beginning of the string.

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($old_array as $a){
    if(substr( $a, 0, 4 ) === "http"){
        array_push($new_array, $a);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe $new_array[] = $a is marginally faster as it avoids the function call, but I've upvoted this answer for code formatting. (Additionally note that it will not throw an error if $new_array is undefined... not that that is necessarily a good thing)

Comment: @RonakPatel do you know why the script would be grabbing the URL (last field in each row) AND the first field of the next row?

Comment: @jeffimperial : What do you mean by that? You want to grab all `URLs` from the array. right?

Comment: @RonakPatel Yup, it's the URL's I am after. But for some reason, if I try to use `$new_array[1]`, it returns the url plus the value of the first field of the next line. It's as if the script isn't detecting line breaks (which indicates separate rows, for treatment as separate items in the array)

Answer (score 0):

```
$new=array();
foreach ($array as $check){

if(substr($check,0,4)=='http')
$new[]=$check;
}
```

Comment: substr($check, 0, 4);*